# How to place tab layout after toolbar?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager, toolbar, android-tablayout

I have a tablayout and a viewpager inside a fragment. i have two tabs in my tablayout. and a toolbar in my app_bar_main.xml. but when i run my app tablayout hides the toolbar. how it can be placed after toolbar?
here is my code
this is my app_bar_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#CC0000"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/white"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_containerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"></FrameLayout>
```

this is my fragment design where i have placed a tab layout and a view pager

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nayab.demotask.ContactsFragment"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/contactstablayot"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
    />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragviewpager"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="#e6f1f5"
    />
```

can somebody please help me out

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? just a single screen with toolbar at top and tablayout below it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` on your Framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

you can use linearlayout with orientation vertical

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#CC0000"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_containerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```